# Selecting item in a string from a starting point retrieved via regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex, selection

So, my situation is the following:
I have a list (half a million, more or less) of string with various elements, like AJIAJAJKAJKAHAKAKG or AOKANSDBSDFBJJ (to make an example).

My goal is to create a script that identifies each string that carry an array of elements defined by the user (say "JIAJA") then, satrting from the last element matched, takes only the N elements after that and append them to a new list, previously set (to continue the example say the script found the pattern in the first string, then set N to 5, retrieves "JKAJK" and append it to a new list).

'till now i can only select those string that match the pattern criteria but i'm still unable to retrieve the N element after that pattern.

The code until now is this:

```
l = open(file, "r").readlines()
s = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in l]
pattern = input("Insert pattern ")
if len(pattern) >=4:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        motif = re.compile('%s' % pattern)
        if re.search(motif, s[i]):
            selection.append(s[i])
        else:
            continue
```

How can i handle the next step?

Comment: for start try to edit your question and make it more clear. people seem not to  understand what you exactly trying to accomplish and its hard to answer. and have a look at the doc too: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: To make more clear the situation is this:
line 1 - AJIAJAJKAJKAHAKAKG
line 2 - AJIAJAJKYGTTARAFHD
line 3 - AOKANSDBSDFBJJGGVV (and so on)
my goal is to identify the lines that carry the pattern "JIAJA", then take the N element from the end of the matched pattern and write in a new list. 
The output, for N=5, must be
Line 1 - JKAJK
Line 2 - JKYGT

I hope this will clarify my question

Comment: @Mojito88 What would be the expected output for this string: `'AJIAJAJKAJKAJIAGAKKKKK'`? (`JIAGA` is repeated twice here)

Comment: if the pattern is repeated twice, find only the first occurring, i don't need to find recursive. Just the first pattern that matches and then count N elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [match.end](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end):

```
line = s[i]
match = re.search(motif, line)
if match:
    selection.append(line[match.end():match.end()+5])
```

---

Using `re.search` will allow users to enter regex patterns. However, if the patterns are simply literal characters, then

```
line = s[i]
idx = line.find(pattern)
if idx >= 0:
    end = idx+len(pattern)
    selection.append(line[end:end+5])
```

would be faster.

---

It is not necessary to compile the pattern

```
motif = re.compile('%s' % pattern)
```

inside the `for-loop` (i.e. once for each line). And since
`re` module caches compiled regex patterns, you could use

```
match = re.search(pattern, line)
```

directly.

---

Also, it is memory-inefficient to read the entire file into a list of lines:

```
open(file, "r").readlines()
s = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in l]
```

Since you are operating on each line one-at-a-time, you could use this pattern instead:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
```

By [using a `with-statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), Python will close `f` for you when execution leaves the `with-suite`.

---

Thus, your code could be rearranged like this:

```
pattern = input("Insert pattern ")
if len(pattern) < 4:
    sys.exit('pattern too short') 

with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            selection.append(line[match.end():match.end()+5])
```